# How to call this function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to call this function in Javascript? 
As it takes *n* as its outer function's parameter and it also needs another parameter *i* in its function inside, but how to call it?

```
function foo(n) { 
  return function (i) { 
           return n += i } }
```

Comment: It does return a function. Call that.

Answer (score 6):

Call the returned value of the function:

```
foo(1)(2);
```

Answer (score 6):

It a classic [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) example: it does return a function which has access to the `n` variable.

```
var counter = foo(0);
counter(1); // 1
counter(2); // 3
counter(5); // 8
```

Comment: It "keeps" the `n` variable that was created in the `foo()` call

Answer (score 4):

This is a function that returns a function.   Often you would want a reference to that function, Like this

```
 foofn = foo(7);
 result = foofn(7);
```

You could also just call the function right away

```
 result = (foo(7))(7);
```

What the function does?  Well that wasn't really your question...

Answer (score 2):

This is the way we usually use JavaScript closures, first function creates a scope to keep the `n` variable safe to be used in the inner function:

```
var n = 11;
var myfunc = foo(n);
```

now you can call your `myfunc` function, with a simple `i` argument, whereas it uses `n` without you needing to pass it directly to your function:

```
myfunc(10);
```

so if you want to just call it, once it is created, you can do: `foo(11)(10);`

But in these cases we don't usually call them like this, they are usually supposed to be used as a callback or something like it.